# Prevent Refresh 'Jump' with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've noticed that if you are on a page and you have scrolled down a good bit, if you refresh the page, most browsers will jump you back down to your position. Is there any way to prevent this?

I have looked at two options and neither are consistent across Webkit / Firefox.

```
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
```

Any ideas?

You can check a google search result for an example.

Comment: This is the opposite of what people usually want.  However, if you simply add a hash `#` to the end of the URL, it will jump to the top on refresh, by default.

Comment: @minitech I read that as the OP wanting to prevent the browser returning to previous scroll position as Sparky672 suggests, and instead returning to the top.

Comment: @minitech: Actually the question is how to prevent the scrolling.

Comment: @minitech - Actually the OP seems to want the opposite, it says "most browsers will jump you back down to your position. Is there any way to prevent this", and for most people that would indicate that the OP would like the page to NOT scroll down to the previous position ?

Comment: To clarify. If a user visits a page and scrolls to 1000px, if they refresh the page, it will have a scroll position of 0, rather than 1000px.

Comment: @Mark Davidson: In that case, Sparky672's initial suggestion should help. I think this should be an answer.

Comment: The suggestion Sparky672 has provided does not work. If you add the # and hit enter, obviously that will. But if you have the # present, then load the page, scroll down, and refresh.. it will not work.

Comment: Firefox automatically does this for me!

Comment: My suggestion was only a suggestion since the context of this question is unknown.  I thought maybe the "refresh" was part of another function.  Since it now seems you simply want to alter the default behavior of the browser, I'd recommend against it... people expect their browser to behave a certain way when then do certain things.  I'm also wondering why this is an issue... is there an unusual reason why your users would be hitting the refresh button?

Comment: I'd agree with Sparky672. Messing with people's browsers is a sure way to angry users, unless you have a really really good use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no reason why this shouldn't work in all browsers, seems to work for me (with only one function for window.onload, use more and there could be problems) ?

```
window.onload = function() {
  scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

To make it work when back button is clicked aswell, maybe something like this:

```
<body onunload="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
       scrollTo(0,0);
    }
</script>
//content here
</body>
```

Comment: What's that empty `onunload=""` doing there?

Comment: The onunload is for the bfcache

Answer (score 15):

Works for me:

```
// Scroll top bro
window.onload = function() {
 setTimeout (function () {
  scrollTo(0,0);
 }, 0);
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer.  The setTimeout helps catch awkward race conditions with some browsers which trigger the scroll jump after the window.onload event.

Comment: agreed, this answer was the one that actually worked for me. Safari 6.1.1 on Mac would at first run my scrollTo code, then jump down to the previous position after page load. doing this won the race.

Comment: This worked perfectly in Google Chrome. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 11):

On Chrome, even if you force scrollTop to 0 it will jump afterwards after the first scroll event.

You should bind the scroll to this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

So the browser is tricked to believe that it was on the beginning before the refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below works for me, create some item that can be focused and focus it to scroll page.

In this case it will scroll back to top after refresh the page.

Tested on latest IE/FF/Chrome.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                setTimeout (function () {
                    // use both 'a' and 'button' because 'a' not work as expected on some browsers
                    document.getElementById('top_anchor').focus();
                    document.getElementById('top_anchor_btn').focus();
                }, 0);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="top_anchor" href="" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -1000px;"></a>
        <button id="top_anchor_btn" href="" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -1000px;"></button>

        <div> top </div>
        <div style="width: 500px; height: 2000px; background-color: #83FEBC;">
            content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Regards,

Ben

Comment: Just make sure do it later, chrome need it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update what @josetapadas said, for recent versions it would be better to use the `unload` function instead of `beforeunload` this will be

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
$(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```